# Is it possible to make smooth transitions between clips in the Unity legacy Animation component?

Tags: unity, animation, animation-controller, animation-states

I'm trying to use the legacy [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html) component for the UI and I can't find a way to make it go from one state to another smoothly. When using the [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html) component the animated parameters change their values smoothly when go from one state to another if the transition duration parameter > 0, but there doesn't seem to be anything like transitions/durations in the legacy [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html) component, so it immediately changes the values. Is there a way to get smooth transitions with the legacy [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The animation component can interpolate between two animation clips with the script method [`Animation.CrossFade`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.CrossFade.html). When you want to transition from the current animation clip to another, you first have to register the clip with the animator using [`AddClip`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.AddClip.html):

```
private Animation myAnimation;
[SerializeField] private AnimationClip secondClip;

void Start() {
    myAnimation = GetComponent<Animation>();
    myAnimation.AddClip(secondClip clipAsset, "second");
}
```

Now you can transition to this new clip with:

```
myAnimation.CrossFade("second", transitionTimeInSeconds);
```

There is also [`CrossFadeQueued`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.CrossFadeQueued.html) which will wait with the transition until the current animation reaches the end of its current loop.

But if you have the requirement to have transitions between different clips, you might really want to consider to migrate from the legacy animation to the (not so) new state-based animation system. It's not just for humanoid characters.

Comment: I tried `CrossFade` and `Blend` with various parameters, but I didn't notice anything like smooth transitions. I'm already using the Animator component system and migrating back to the legacy: my UI began to show delays during activation due to the large number of buttons with animations. They recommend reducing the number of animators in this article (at the very bottom): https://unity.com/how-to/unity-ui-optimization-tips
In another article the recommended using the legacy animation system for the UI.

Comment: If I fail with the legacy animation I will animate it in code, but this is a rather non-visual way when it comes to animating a lot of parameters.